# Hybris starts server for unit tests

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm wondering why does Hybris start server for running unit tests.
I'm using hybris 1808 with telco accelerator 1810. I'm using command `ant unittests`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first initialize the junit tenant. Kindly open hac and check for the tenants. If Junit tenant is not there then add the following property to the local.properties and restart the server.
installed.tenants=junit
Then initialize the junit tenant.
Then the command ant unittests or ant allTests will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start the server.
 In fact, you can skip the initialization of *junit tenant* as well if you are not using any data from the *junit tenant* i.e. if you are creating all the required data in the junit class itself.
Sample 
 command for running *junits* :

> ant unittests -Dtestclasses.extensions=basecommerce,core

[More details](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=release5&title=Testing%20in%20the%20hybris%20Commerce%20Suite#TestinginthehybrisCommerceSuite-Ant).

Comment: Why is Hybris 5 link given in Hybris 1811 question. They have even discontinued updating that portal. Where can I find the info in 1811 and above documentation